# Creating static popup in OpenLayers that contains HTML content?

Tags: openlayers-2, html

I would like to create a static popup using openLayers 2.11 which is always in the lower-right corner of the screen and appears on map load.  The idea behind this is to have a logo for my school always appear.  I already have a marker layer setup.  Maybe I am approaching this incorrectly.

I have tried using some of the examples on the OpenLayers website regarding anchored popups with no luck.

The contents of the popup are as follows:

```
    <div id="cube" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color-#575757;">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/cube.css">
    <div class="wrap">
<div class="cube">
    <div class="front">front</div>
    <div class="back">back</div>
    <div class="top">top</div>
    <div class="bottom">bottom</div>
    <div class="left">left</div>
    <div class="right">right</div>
</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the position of logo is static and not feature-dependent, then you don't need a popup. You can use an ordinary div element positioned over the map (just make sure that the CSS z-index is high enough, more than 1000), or put the HTML content in markers layer 'attribution' property and add the following CSS rule:

```
.olControlAttribution {
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

to place the content in lower-right corner of the map.

Comment: Thank you for your response Michal!  I have tried setting up another div for the content, however, I have been unable to get it positioned over the map div.  Can you provide me with an example I could use?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: A quick-and-dirty example: http://jsfiddle.net/jL8bD/ This is a div with some content (image+text) placed in upper-right corner of the map. The z-index value of 1000 might be not enough for a more complex map with many layers, play with Firebug or Chrome Dev Tools to figure out a right z-index for your application.

Comment: Michal's answer link is perfect!  Thank you for solving my problem!